# Modify WooCommerce archive product page to show SKU for every product

Tags: php, woocommerce

As a standard, WooCommerce archive page show the products with image, title and buy"button" stacked on a block side by side. What i want is to also have it to show custom fields e.g. SKU , color etc.

I've tried to add

```
$block_data['sku'] = $product->get_sku();
```

and then

```
$layout['sku'] = array();
```

the result of the code (this is just a part of the .php file):

```
$block_data['content'] = get_the_content();
$block_data['classes'] = $block_classes;
$block_data['tmb_data'] = $tmb_data;
$block_data['id'] = $post->ID;
$block_data['media_id'] = $item_thumb_id;
$block_data['title_classes'] = $title_classes;
$block_data['link'] = get_permalink();
$block_data['text_length'] = 300;
$block_data['product'] = true;
$block_data['sku'] = $product->get_sku();

$categories_id = array();
$categories_link = array();
$woo_categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if (isset($woo_categories) && !empty($woo_categories)) {
    foreach ( $woo_categories as $woo_cat ) {
        $woo_cat_id = $woo_cat->term_id; //category ID
        $woo_cat_name = $woo_cat->name; //category name



$block_data['single_categories_id'] = $categories_id;
$block_data['single_categories'] = $categories_link;


if ($item_thumb_id !== '') {
    $layout['media'] = array();

} else {
    $layout['media'] = array('placeholder');

}
$layout['title'] = array();
$layout['price'] = array();
$layout['sku'] = array();
```

I expected the output to be in this order image - title -price - SKU, but it doesn't output any SKU

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your current active theme `functions.php`

ADD SKU after Product Title

```
function woocommerce_item_sku_on_archive()  {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
        echo $product->get_sku();
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_item_sku_on_archive');
```

ADD SKU AFTER PRODUCT PRICE

```
function custom_sku_after_price_loop( $price ) { 
    global $product;
    if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
        $sku = $product->get_sku();
        return $price . '<br /><span class="product-sku">' . $sku . '</span>';
    }else { 
        return $price; 
    } 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_sku_after_price_loop' );
```

Comment: This code does add the SKU to the shop archive page, but instead add it after the price label in each of every product, it just getting outputted on the top of the page separated from the products.

Comment: you want it after product price?

Comment: @jan I have updated my answer and added how you can add the sku after product price please check